# Mean vs survival analysis

Tags: survival

What is the need of survival analysis over simply using the mean of lifetimes (of died subjects)?

For example: Through recorded data we can probably calculate the lifetime of a human on earth as a mean of 82034340 or so people. Could I do it as that or would I need survival analysis for that?

Another example: In case I'm a car manufacturer which released a new car and after a year I want to know their lifetime. I know that 20 % cars failed.
I guess I definitely have to use survival analysis here but how would I argue on doing so?
Would it change anything whether 20 %, 40 %, 60 %, 80 % or 100 % failed within the first year?

Comment: Survival analysis has more to do with censored data, if you have no censoring then you do not really need survival analysis.

Comment: Re "recorded data:" those are data only about people who have died.  Those who are still alive tend to be longer-lived than those who have died!  (This is true even in a population with static mortality rates.)

Comment: Thanks, in case I would have the data of all devices resp. the information of when each device failed, then I could simply use the mean for the estimation, right? And I guess this would also be okish if I had information of only 90 % of all subjects?